# In Terraform, how can I create an iterative list out of two aws_subnet objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

New to Terraform. I have two `aws_subnet` objects which I want to associate with route tables. As I understand it, each AZ will need it's own route table. The easiest thing to do would be just declare two route tables, one for each subnet but would like to know if there is a better way to do it instead of just settling for things thrown together.

I have declared my subnets as a list in `variables.tf`:

```
variable "my_public_subnets" {
  type         = list
  description  = "public subnet within vpc cidr block"
  default      = ["10.1.2.0/24", "10.1.1.0/24"]
}
```

And have two public subnets in `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_subnet" "pub_1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.my_public_subnets[0]
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}
    
resource "aws_subnet" "pub_2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.my_public_subnets[1]
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
}
```

Instead of:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "pub_ra_1" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.pub_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.bar.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "pub2_ra_2" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.pub_2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.bar.id
}
```

Is there way to do something like this? Create a list/array/map of those two subnets so I don't have to declare a `aws_route_table_association` for both of them? Maybe there's a better way to set this up in general?

```
locals {
  my_pub_subnets = [aws_subnet.pub_1, aws_subnet.pub_2]
}

resource "aws_route_table_association"  "pub_rt_a" {
  for_each                = locals.my_pub_subnets
  subnet_id               = each.value
  route_table_id          = aws_route_table.some_public_route_table.id
  depends_on              = [aws_subnet.pub_1]
}
```

Comment: The route table association should be the same for both subnets?

Comment: No you're not, just maybe lost your focus. Can you say in the question what exactly you want to achieve so I can undelete my answer? :)

Comment: @MarkoE - That could be. I've been trying to undo some modules for a lift and shift that got bumped in priority up this week. The broader question would be something like "How do I get my TF skillset up to speed in a week?" but this is all part of a larger management brush fire. I will need to come back when I have time and refactor much of this.

Comment: @Nstevens, if you want to upgrade your TF' game, then make a habit of pilfering the code in TF modules example directories. Theres lots of good stuff in there

Comment: Good to know that's a helpful resource. Everytime I follow a github link from terraform.io I see things done differently which helps. Recently found out about TF input files and now I realize why I see so many empty defaults in other's `variables.tf`

Comment: @MarkoE - I've edited the question with a little less haste. I thank you and JoshBeauregard for taking the time to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are how you create repeatable procedures in TF.

Something like:

```
locals{
subnets = {
public = "10.1.2.0/24",
private = "10.1.1.0/24"
}

module "subnets" {
 source = "./modules/subnets"
 for_each                = subnets

 name = each.key
 cidr = each.value
}
```

for the AZ names, you could also use `data.aws_availability_zones.available.names`

I would guess that most of you want is really well done inside the [VPC module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest).

You would have to import the VPC into your state to start, but this is how I do my subnets with it.

```
locals {
 subnets         = chunklist(cidrsubnets("10.2.8.0/24", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 2)
  public_subnets  = local.subnets[1]
  private_subnets = local.subnets[2]
}
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  count    = length(local.private_subnets)

  vpc  = true


}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.14.0"

  name                 = "foo"
  cidr                 = "10.2.8.0/24"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = local.private_subnets
  public_subnets       = local.public_subnets
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  single_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  reuse_nat_ips        = true # <= Skip creation of EIPs for the NAT Gateways
  external_nat_ip_ids  = aws_eip.nat.*.id

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "Tier" = "Public"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "Tier" = "Private"
  }
}

output "public_subnets" {
  value       = module.vpc.public_subnets

}
output "public_subnets_cidr" {
  value       = module.vpc.public_subnets_cidr_blocks

}
output "private_subnets" {
  value       = module.vpc.private_subnets

}
output "private_subnets_cidr" {
  value       = module.vpc.private_subnets_cidr_blocks

}
```

Comment: Thanks much. I've been trying to get my head around modules and I don't have a great grasp of it yet. I'll get there. Snippets like this do help.

Comment: @Nstevens modules are a way of making re-usable functions in TF. I have this starter module that I use, it even has example unit tests (thats right you can unit test terraform) https://github.com/sanguis/terraform-module-scaffolding

Comment: Thanks again! Unit tests...using Go nonetheless? This blows my mind but makes perfect sense for something as complex as an entire IaaS configuration.

Comment: The `vpc` module is probably fine for what I need but I had a problem declaring an `aws_datasync_location_efs` object which wanted a single `subnet_arn`. I had declared `my_private_subnets` as a list of strings and fed to the `vpc` module that way. I could not figure out how to get a `subnet_arn` out of the `vpc` module so ended up removing the `vpc` module so I could give `aws_subnets` an actual `subnet_arn`.  This is not the way I wanted to learn TF but I find out my mistakes every day so learning something anyway.. ha

Comment: have you looked at https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest?tab=outputs ?

Comment: Yes, that was one module I was using. I spent the better part a day trying to figure out how to get a `subnet_arn` out of the module for the  `aws_datasync_location_efs` object but ended up at a dead end so pulled it out to define `aws_subnet` objects by hand. There is a `private_subnet_arns` listed in the outputs so thought it would be fine but I couldn't make sense of the errors I was getting. I might be confusing `attributes` and `outputs` so there's that.

Comment: its going to to be somthing along the lines of `module.foo.public_subnet_arns[0]`

Comment: I just remembered I posted about that question here, yesterday. The details should be there if you need a brain teaser: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17450/subnet-arn-for-datasync-location-using-terraform-vpc-module  I used `${element...` but basically the same thing?